# Same url, work like reference to style, but doesn't work like AJAX call

Tags: css, ajax, load

This is code work fine:

```
      {html}
      {head>
           {**link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:3000/CSS/mystyle.css"**}
      {/head}
      {body}
      {/body}
      {/html}
```

But this code with same url give me problem: 
**XMLHttpRequest cannot load "href="http://localhost:3000/CSS/mystyle.css". Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.**

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

               var href = 'http://localhost:3000/CSS/mystyle.css';

               $.ajax({
                   url: href,
                  dataType: 'text/css',
                   success: function(data) {
                       $('\n' + data + '').appendTo("head");
                   }
               });
           });
```

Really don't understand what is problem, both call HttpRequest ?
Thanks, for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer will be to use a local web server like WAMP(or IIS) if you are not already.

the second answer is

Chrome and Safari has a restriction on using ajax with local resources. That's why it's throwing an error like

> *Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.*

**Solution:** Use firefox or upload your data to a temporary server. If you still want to use Chrome, start it with the below option;

```
--allow-file-access-from-files
```

**More info how to add the above parameter to your Chrome:** Right click the Chrome icon on your task bar, right click the Google Chrome on the pop-up window and click properties and add the above parameter inside the Target textbox under Shortcut tab. It will like as below;

```
C:\Users\XXX_USER\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files
```